# change flexslider thumbnail with text

Tags: jquery, html, flexslider

What I want to do is to change the flexslider thumbnails to text and remove images.This is what I mean .This is the default flexslider  :

[image]

and I'm trying to convert the thumbnail section to be like this :

[image]

So ,instead of displaying images as thumbnails , I would display textes.

This is the code I'm using :

```
   <div class="flexslider  " >
                                    <ul class="slides ">
                                        <li data-thumb="assets/img/slider/1.jpg">
                                            <img src="assets/img/slider/1.jpg">

                                        </li>
                                        <li data-thumb="assets/img/slider/2.jpg">
                                            <img src="assets/img/slider/2.jpg">

                                        </li>
                                        <li data-thumb="assets/img/slider/5.jpg">
                                            <img src="assets/img/slider/5.jpg">

                                        </li>
                                        <li data-thumb="assets/img/slider/6.jpg">
                                            <img src="assets/img/slider/6.jpg">

                                        </li>
                                    </ul>

                            </div>
<script>
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            controlNav: "thumbnails",
            start: function (){
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

How could I do so ?

Thanks

Comment: did your flexslider provided by WooThemes?

Comment: @JackyShek yes,it does

Comment: i have searched that there is no theme of the slider to support your purpose which means that the second slider does not existing in WooThemes. You need to find another slider plugin to support your purpose. if you still want to use this slider plugin, you need to edit the plugin javascrpt, but not guarantee that is work properly.